# Visualizing an Affine Matrix

Tags: matrix, visualization, geometric-transform

I have a computer graphics program that prints out affine matrices like

```
Transform Basis: V3 (V3 0.99060506 (-1.4430956e-2) 0.1359906) (V3 1.381684e-2 0.9998897 5.458703e-3) (V3 (-0.13605437) (-3.5284583e-3) 0.9906951) 
Transform Position: V3 0.4690141 0.6664715 0.16474605
```

Is there a way to visualize this matrix in Mathematica (in some sort of 3D plot)?  Say of where it sends the origin looking forward?

Answer (score 6):

```
inputstring = 
  "Transform Basis: V3 (V3 0.99060506 (-1.4430956e-2) 0.1359906) (V3 1.381684e-2 0.9998897 5.458703e-3) (V3 (-0.13605437) (-3.5284583e-3) 0.9906951) 
  Transform Position: V3 0.4690141 0.6664715 0.16474605";

lines = StringSplit[
  StringDelete[inputstring, {
    "(", ")",
    RegularExpression["V\\d+"],
    RegularExpression["Transform.*?:"]}], "\n"];

getnumbers[line_] := Module[{parts},
  parts = Flatten[StringCases[StringSplit[line], RegularExpression["-?[\\d.e]+-?\\d+"]]];
  ToExpression[StringReplace[#, "e" -> "*^"]] & /@ Flatten[parts]
]

m = ArrayReshape[getnumbers[lines[[1]]], {3, 3}];
v = getnumbers[lines[[2]]];
Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[.25],
  Blue, Cuboid[],
  Red, GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[], {m, v}]
}]
```

[image: affine transform vis]

Since it's an affine transform `m.p + v`, the origin is displaced from `{0,0,0}` to `v`.

Comment: Nifty! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It should be noted that the transformation function itself can be obtained as `AffineTransform[{m, v}]`.